# Mean value theorem implies first fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: real-analysis

My book states, that if we apply the "mean value theorem in integral form" on $f'$, then follows: $\int_a^b{f'} = (b-a)f'(c)$. If we compare this with the "canonical mean value theorem": $f(b) - f(a) = (b-a)f'(c)$, then this suggests that $\int_a^b{f'} = f(b) - f(a)$.
It also states that although the former suggests the latter, it doesn't *prove* the latter.

My question is why isn't this a proof?

Comment: I think it's a circular argument, since this theorem depends FFTC

Comment: @dwarandae what is fftc?

Comment: The $c$s are only the same if you know the latter equality holds. If you just know both LHS are equal to the same RHS at some $c$, those could be different $c$s.

Comment: @xcrypt First Fundamentel Theorem of Calculus, sorry.

Comment: Ah @gnometorule that will most likely be the reason. Variables with same names but different meanings get so confusing... Thanks. But maybe your comment should be an answer :)

Comment: @dwarandae No in our book both these theorems get proven before the first fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: You can establish the mean value theorem using Rolle's and Heine-Borel theorems. After that, you can prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus using the mean value theorem and Darboux sums. This is what Rudin's Principles does.

Comment: I believe Spivak does this also in his _Calculus_.